# Overwriting subsection of Excel file with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a large (90-120mb) excel file that generates a monthly report I do. Every month new data comes in that needs to be inserted into columns A:K on one sheet with formulas in J on that create some sub report items. In the past, new data was cleaned manually in excel, however, I have been writing a python script that will do this heavy lifting for me. Currently the data is cleaned, but I cannot figure out how to export to the specific range I need it to go into, without overwriting all other 'data'.

I've tried:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet']
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=11):
     for cell in row:
          cell.value = None
wb.save('workbook.xlsx')
```

However, my issue here is that the file cannot be loaded via openpyxl. The command will run for roughly an hour before throwing me a memory error, and I know that this code works on a smaller file.

I've read nearly every thread I could find via google and nothing has yet worked. I am aware openpyxl has a write_only mode, but as far as I can find in the documentation this doesn't allow for one: the use of a pre-existing file, nor two: the targeting of specific cells.

I've been able to do similar things via R and STATA which I am more familiar with, but for this specific project Python is mandatory for the automation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Python 3.9.7
Pandas 1.3.5
Openpyxl 3.0.9

Comment: Hi, you can give a check to 'xlwings' library, which I use very often and find it useful and for some tasks, better than others, link: https://www.xlwings.org/ 

What it does is opening an Excel instance which operate on the file. If you add some more info about your file, we can help you better with code.

Comment: If you're getting a memory error for a large file, and not for a small file, then obviously your file is too large. It may be easiest to read the file in read only, saving each line to a list and appending to a master list, then writing in write only mode to a new file that is used to replace your old file. Without testing I'm unsure if this would be more optimized